# Using a notification with which I retrieve the orientation change before it occurs

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nsnotificationcenter

Because `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` is to late for me I thought I use `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`.

This is how I subscribe:

```
observer = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ((NSString)UIApplication.WillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, UpdateIntrinsicConstraints);
```

Now I want to extract the orientation

```
public void UpdateIntrinsicConstraints(NSNotification notification){
    // Cannot convert type 'Foundation.NSObject' to 'UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation'
    switch ((UIInterfaceOrientation)notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey(UIApplication.StatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey))
    {
        case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

, but I can't convert from `NSObject` to `UIInterfaceOrientation`.

Is `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` right for me and how can I extract the orientation to which the interface rotates (like `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you get from

```
notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey(UIApplication.StatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey)
```

is an NSNumber. So you have to get that NSNumber's value as Int. Then you can cast that int to UIInterfaceOrientation.
Same thing in code:

```
short shortValue = ((NSNumber)notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey(UIApplication.StatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey)).Int16Value;
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = ((UIInterfaceOrientation)shortValue);
switch (orientation)
 {
     case UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
         // ...
         break;
      default:
         break;
 }
```

Or if you prefer the same in one line:

```
switch ((UIInterfaceOrientation)((NSNumber)notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey(UIApplication.StatusBarOrientationUserInfoKey)).Int16Value)
```